# Group policy - restart specific service if it stops

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-services

If you want to restart a service if it fails on a single computer this is done by changing a setting on the service in `services.msc`. But the same option does not seem to exist when you want to do the same thing via a group policy. The only option I can find is to choose if you want the service to start or not on boot.

Is there a simple way to achieve this on many computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Group Policy Preferences to configure a service failure action. In the GPMC GPO editor go to [Computer Configuration > Preferences > Control Panel Settings > Services]. Create a new service with the same name of the service you wish to configure. Then go to the Recovery tab and select your failure actions (eg "Restart Service")

[image]

You can use the Item Level Targeting in the 'Common' tab to target specific Domains/Computers/Groups if required.